# JavaScript Events onfocus and onblur

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying `onfocus` and `onblur` events. It's not working. When I click the email field the value does not disappears. Here's my code. Please tell me if there's anything wrong:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>More Events</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" value="your email" name="email" id="email" />
        </form>
    
        <script>
            var emailField = document.getElementById('email');
             emailField.onfocus = function(c) {
                if (emailField.value == 'your email')
                    {
                        emailField.value == '';
                    }
                }
             emailField.onblur = function(c) {
                if (emailField.value == '')
                    {
                        emailField.value == 'your email';
                    }
                
             }
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your events is fine, it's just typo in assignment of emailField.value. You should use single = instead of ==.

Comment: onblur event is still not working..

Comment: Maybe using `placeholder` attribute is what you need. `<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your email" />`. See http://jsfiddle.net/234dk2q1/

Comment: Interesting, what browser do you use? Checkout working example on plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/UXXXqrEfndLx4FyOC8bu?p=preview. And btw  placeholder attribute provides similar functionality without js at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using comparison operator(`==`) instead of assignment operator(`=`) here:

```
emailField.value == '';
```

Change it to

```
emailField.value = '';
```

In code:

```
var emailField = document.getElementById('email');
         emailField.onfocus = function(c) {
            if (emailField.value == 'your email')
                {
                    emailField.value = '';
                }
            }
         emailField.onblur = function(c) {
            if (emailField.value == '')
                {
                    emailField.value = 'your email';//Also here
                }

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using double equal to to assign:

```
emailField.value == '';
```

should be

```
emailField.value = '';
```

And in the else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator are wrong,
change

```
emailField.value == '';
...
emailField.value == 'your email';
```

to

```
emailField.value = '';
...
emailField.value = 'your email';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="your email" name="email" id="email" onfocus="function(this)" />
</form>

<script>
    var emailField = document.getElementById('email');
     emailField.onfocus = function(c) {
        if (emailField.value == 'your email')
            {
                emailField.value = ''; // Here was the problem use assignment operator(=) here emailField.value == '';
            }
        }
     emailField.onblur = function(c) {
        if (emailField.value == '')
            {
                emailField.value = 'your email'; // Here was the problem use assignment operator(=) here emailField.value == '';
            }

     }
</script>
```